# multi level dictionary with spark from rdd

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a mongoDB with ~6 millions document, I want to explore my data to analyse it and I want process them to have a dictionnary to have a better comprehension

I do a flatmap (`rdd.flatMap(process_document)`) so I have a list (of tuples because my `process_document` function returns a list of tuples). This is an example of this list:

```
result_rdd.take(1)

[('ip', 1, ('id', 'ttl', 0), ('Tuesday-WorkingHours/_53148_20170704144537.pcap', 21))]
```

It's what I want but now I want transform this list of tuples into a multi level dictionary. Each tuple has 4 elements, so I want a 3 levels dictionary. I want to get a value like this

```
my_dict[key1][key2][key3]
```

I tried to use `foldByKey` without success, this is what I tried:

```
def construct_dict(acc, value):
    nbr_empty, context, location = value
    acc[nbr_empty][context] = location

    return acc

rdd = df.rdd

result_rdd = rdd.flatMap(process_document)

default_value = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: [])))

my_dict = result_rdd.foldByKey(default_value, construct_dict).collectAsMap()
```

In `construct_dict`, `acc` has only 2 levels because `foldByKey` handles the first level (if I well understood)

Unfortunately, python gives me a cryptic error message because spark uses java engine:

```
{Py4JJavaError}An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 13 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 13.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 14) (*ip* executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/deep-learning/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 830, in main
    process()
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/deep-learning/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 820, in process
    out_iter = func(split_index, iterator)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/deep-learning/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 5405, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  F...
```

So I have no clue of what happens

EDIT:

To be more clear, I gave an example of my input (list of tuples after flatMap):

```
[('ip', 1, ('id', 'ttl', 0), ('Tuesday-WorkingHours/_53148_20170704144537.pcap', 21))]
```

and the output I want (for this example) is:

```
{ 
 "ip": {
      1: {
         ('id', 'ttl', 0): [
                    ('Tuesday-WorkingHours/_53148_20170704144537.pcap', 21),
              .....
              ]
         .....
         }
       .....
     }
  .....
}
```

First keys will be always string. Second ones always integers. The third ones always tuples of (string, string, int). And the value always a list of tuple of (string, int)

Comment: Hey would be easier if you paste a dataframe snippet of the input and the dict output you want to achieve

Comment: @Yefet it's done :) I hope it's understandable, for each level I give only one example else I think it could be unreadable

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. I couldn't find a generic way to merge two dictionaries to fit the structure you expected. The helper function `mergeDicts` has some edge cases not implemented (Ex: two dictionaries with overlapping keys).

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

def mergeDicts(dict1, dict2):
    result = {}
    keysFromDict1 = dict1.keys()
    keysFromDict2 = dict2.keys()
    # keys need to be sorted for array comparison to work
    if keysFromDict1 == keysFromDict2:
        for k in keysFromDict1:
            result[k] = {}
            numberObj = dict1[k]
            numberObj1 = dict2[k]
            keysFromNumObj = numberObj.keys()
            keysFromNumObj1 = numberObj1.keys()
            # keys need to be sorted for array comparison to work
            if keysFromNumObj == keysFromNumObj1:
                for k1 in keysFromNumObj:
                    result[k][k1] = []
                    result[k][k1] = result[k][k1] + numberObj[k1]
                    result[k][k1] = result[k][k1] + numberObj1[k1]
            else:
                for k1 in keysFromNumObj:
                    result[k][k1] = []
                    result[k][k1] = result[k][k1] + numberObj[k1]
                for k2 in keysFromNumObj1:
                    result[k][k2] = []
                    result[k][k2] = result[k][k2] + numberObj1[k2]
    else:
        for k in keysFromDict1:
            result[k] = dict1[k]
        for k1 in keysFromDict2:
            result[k1] = dict2[k1]
    return result

def tupleToDict(tuple):
    keyTuple1 = {tuple[2]: [tuple[3]]}
    numberObj1 = {tuple[1] : keyTuple1}
    return (tuple[0], numberObj1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #Initialize Spark context
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName("FoldByKeyExample")
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

    # Sample data
    data = [('ip', 1, ('id', 'ttl', 0), ('Tuesday-WorkingHours/_53148_20170704144537.pcap', 21)),
        ('ip', 2, ('id', 'ttl', 0), ('Tuesday-WorkingHours/_53148_20170704144538.pcap', 21))
    ]
    rdd = sc.parallelize(data)

    inputRdd = rdd.map(tupleToDict)

    # Use foldByKey to aggregate underlying dict
    initial_value = {}
    result_rdd = inputRdd.foldByKey(initial_value, mergeDicts)
    # Collect the results and print them
    results = result_rdd.collectAsMap()
    print(results)

    # Stop the Spark context
    sc.stop()
```